# Buill and minify LESS files and minify JS files using Webpack

Tags: webpack

I am trying to migrate a small project's (mostly server side with a few LESS and JS files) client build from Gulp to Webpack.

I have the following paths:
- "styles/reset.less"
- "styles/mixins.less"
- "styles/styles.less"
- "scripts/scripts.js"

I only need to:

1 - Compile the less files into one "app.css" file and minify it to "app.min.css".
2 - Minify the "scripts.js" file into "app.min.js".

I have the following package.json file:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.21.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "less-loader": "4.1.0"
  }
}
```

And created the following webpack.config.js file:

```
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {

  module: {
    rules: [{
      test: /\.less$/,
      loader: 'less-loader', options: {
        strictMath: true,
        noIeCompat: true
      }
    }]
  }  

};
```

How can I configure webpack to make (1) and (2)?

A side question: is it possible to rebuild when one of these files change?

**Update**

Following Rick van Osta answer I updated package.json to:

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --watch"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "webpack": "4.21.0",
    "webpack-cli": "3.1.2",
    "css-loader": "1.0.0",
    "less-loader": "4.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "0.4.4",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "5.0.1",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "2.0.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

And webpack.config.js to:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');

var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
var OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
var UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {

  plugins: [
    new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: 'styles.min.css',
    })
  ],

  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js'],
  },

  entry: {
    'scripts.min': './scripts/scripts.js',
  },  

  output: {
    filename: "[name].js"
  },

  optimization: {
    minimizer: [
      new UglifyJsPlugin({
        cache: true,
        parallel: true,
        sourceMap: false
      }),
      new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
    ]
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.less$/,
        use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, 'css-loader', 'less-loader']
      }
    ]
  }

};
```

I then ran webpack using and I got the following errors:

```
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/less-loader/dist/cjs.js):
Error: Cannot find module 'less'
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, your post contains A LOT of questions. It would be better to separate them in different ones. Anyway, your questions are to:

- Resolve LESS files
- Compile LESS to CSS
- Minify CSS
- Extract CSS to another file (This isn't a part of your question, but webpack is called a 'bundler' for a reason. It *will* include CSS in a single bundle.)
- Minify Javascript
- Rebuild when changed

I could just slap together a config file for you, but where's the fun in that?

### Compiling LESS to CSS & Resolving LESS

If you want to compile your less into css using webpack, you have to import the file into your Javascript. Otherwise, webpack won't know what files you want to include. Rules just tell webpack what to do with imports of less files. It won't look for them on its own. Also, you need to set your Javascript file as your entry point. Make sure that the styles.less file imports the other less files in order to get the complete css file, or import all less files individually.

```
// scripts.js
import "../styles/styles.less";
...
```

The webpack config should have the entry point set (very important, even if you just wanted to do the Javascript part):

```
// webpack.config.js
module.exports = {
...
resolve: {
    extensions: [".js"],
},
entry: {
    'app.min': "./scripts/scripts.js",
},
output: {
    filename: "[name].js"
},
...
```

Your less-loader will do the rest.

### Minify CSS

Webpack 5 will probably contain a minifier to do this for you, but with webpack 4 you need to bring your own. A good css optimizer would be the [optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin](https://github.com/NMFR/optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin).

First off, install the plugin using npm.

```
npm install optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then, include it at the top of your config file.

```
var OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require("optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin");
```

And finally, set the plugin as your very own minifier.

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
  ]
},
```

### Extract CSS to another file

To do this, you will also need a plugin. A fitting one for this task would be the [mini-css-extract-plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/mini-css-extract-plugin).

First, install the plugin.

```
npm install mini-css-extract-plugin --save-dev
```

You would also need both the LESS loader and CSS loader for this task, so install those aswell. Assuming you already have the less-loader, the following would be enough.

```
npm install css-loader --save-dev
```

Then, include it in the config:

```
var MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
```

After that, include it as a plugin in your config:

```
plugins: [
  new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
    filename: 'app.min.css',
  })
],
```

And finally, include the plugin loader in your loader configuration.

```
module: {
  rules: [
    {
      test: /\.less$/,
      use: [
        MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        'css-loader',
        'less-loader',
      ],
    }
  ]
}
```

### Minify Javascript code

In order to minify the Javascript, you should include a webpack minify plugin. A good example of this would be the [uglifyjs webpack plugin](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/uglifyjs-webpack-plugin).

First, install the plugin using npm.

```
npm install uglifyjs-webpack-plugin --save-dev
```

Then, require the plugin at the top of your webpack config.

```
var uglify = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
```

Lastly, define your plugin in the webpack config, along with the previously mentioned CSS minifier.

```
optimization: {
  minimizer: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      cache: true,
      parallel: true,
      sourceMap: true // set to true if you want JS source maps
    }),
    new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
  ]
},
```

This will ensure that whenever webpack runs, the plugin is fired and will minify (using uglifyjs) your code.

### Recompile your code on change

This one's the easy one. Webpack comes with a built-in flag to watch your code for changes.

Just add `-w` to your call, and it will watch your code.

```
webpack -w
```

I might have missed a lot due to the large amount of questions, but this should at least get you started.

Comment: First of all let me thank you for the great explanation. I just added an update to my question with the new webpack configuration file and package.json that I came up after reading your answer. However I am getting an error which until now I was not able to solve. Do you know what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

Comment: @MiguelMoura Glad to hear you’ve got it up and running. You’re welcome.